# inl file cause redifine

Tags: c++, inline

I am learning SFML and I have:

```
#include "TextureHolder.inl"
```

in my Textureholder.hpp file. And my TextureHolder.inl file is as follows:

```
sf::Texture& TextureHolder::get(Textures::ID id){
auto result = mTextureMap.find(id);
return *result ->second;
}

void TextureHolder::load(Textures::ID id, const std::string& filename){
std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> texture(new sf::Texture);

texture ->loadFromFile(filename);
mTextureMap.insert(std::make_pair(id, std::move(texture)));
}
```

When I builded the project, an redefine error of function load and get occured.

And when I put `#include "TextureHolder.inl"` in my Game.cpp, it works. So does it mean that every implementation should be placed in the source code instead of head file?

How should I handle the problem?

Comment: Did you declare those functions inline in the class declaration?

Comment: I declare inline in my hpp file and it works fine. But why would this happen in VS2010? It works fine in VS2008...

Comment: Fairly important to make an .inl file that you #include in multiple translation units contain functions that are actually declared *inline*.